# Как реализовать композицию функций в javascript

Tags: javascript

В функциональном программировании есть такое понятие, как чистота функций и композиция. При вычислениях внутри функций не изменяются значения переменных внешнего мира. Производим вычисления в одной функции, и результат передаем дальше, в другую функцию. В javascript в качестве примера можно привести:

```
[].map().reduce();
```

Все они связаны сущностью Array. Из функтора map() в reduce() передаются обработанные значения массива.  Хотелось бы узнать, как пишутся такие функции? Как они устроены внутри, как осуществляется в них композиция ("склеивание" через точку)?

**UPDATE**

Примерно такой принцип?

```
var Test = function() {

    var map = function() {
        console.log('map');
        return new Test();
    };

    var reduce = function() {
        console.log('reduce');
        return new Test();
    };

    return {
        map : map,
        reduce : reduce
    };

};

var test = new Test();
test.map().reduce()
// map
// reduce
```

Или как-то все же по-другому?

Comment: здесь нет композиции функции: есть просто объект, у которого есть набор функции, и данные функции просто возвращают объект того же типа

Comment: @Grundy спасибо. обновил вопрос. Вы примерно это имели ввиду?

Comment: да, реализация не совсем, лучше функции запхнуть в прототип и из Test убрать `return` - а в остальном именно это

Comment: @MatveySafronov посмотрите исходники того же Immutable https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/src/ все должно быть понятно, например метода Map

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев ухх большое спасибо! я реально искал подобное

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Хотелось бы узнать, как пишутся такие функции?

Функция просто должна возвращать какое то значение.

> Как они устроены внутри, как осуществляется в них композиция
>   ("склеивание" через точку)?

В самой функции этого нет, склеивание через точку это конструкция языка (оператор точка с левой ассоциативностью).

Comment: Наверное херню скажу - но точка разве не для доступа к полям объекта только используется? Или это и называется оператор точка с левой ассоциативностью?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian это вещи перпендикулярные. Оператор и его отдельные свойства мало говорят о том, что именно оператор делает. Да, это он же.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Функция это и есть метод объекта. При этом функция сама является объектом и так же может иметь свои свойства и методы.

Comment: Раньше просто только в C++ слышал, что точка это оператор, в js первый раз.